# AppStructure - Passing useRef object from react service to component

Tags: reactjs

I am restructuring a component where I am moving websocket and WebRTC calls to a 'service' file - I'm doing this because I need to separate the concerns of making these calls and the re-rendering and state of the component. Before I moved the code out of the component I used `useRef` to target a video element, but now on separation I can't quite figure out haw to pass `local video` from the service to the component. Should I be using callbacks in some way?

Would really appreciate any help as this is part of a college project I need to finish, many thanks!

First block of code is the service, second is the component.

```
var localVideo;
var localStream;
var remoteVideo;
var peerConnection;
var uuid;
var serverConnection;

var peerConnectionConfig = {
  'iceServers': [
    { 'urls': 'stun:stun.stunprotocol.org:3478' },
    { 'urls': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
  ]
};

uuid = createUUID();

serverConnection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8444');
serverConnection.onmessage = gotMessageFromServer;

var constraints = {
  video: true,
  audio: true,
};

localVideo = // USED TO BE ASSIGNED useRef()
remoteVideo = // USED TO BE ASSIGNED useRef()

if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(getUserMediaSuccess).catch(errorHandler);
} else {
  alert('Your browser does not support getUserMedia API');
}

function getUserMediaSuccess(stream) {
  localStream = stream;
  localVideo.srcObject = stream; // THIS REQUIRES localvideo
}


//  CALL ONCLICK
export function start(isCaller) {
  // CALL CONTACT VIA SOCKET IO
  peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(peerConnectionConfig);
  peerConnection.onicecandidate = gotIceCandidate;
  peerConnection.ontrack = gotRemoteStream;
  peerConnection.addStream(localStream);
  if (isCaller) {
    peerConnection.createOffer().then(createdDescription).catch(errorHandler);
  }
}

// ===================================================================
```

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import Countdown from './Countdown';
import { makeOutGoing } from '../services/WebSocketService'
import { Button } from 'antd';
import { start } from '../services/CallCallerService'

function CallPaneCaller(props) {

  console.log("RENDERRRRRING")

  localVideo = useRef(); // HOW TO ACCESS THIS FROM THE SERVICE??
  remoteVideo = useRef();

const handleOnClick = () => {
  start(true)
  makeOutGoing(props)
}

  return (
    <>
      <video autoPlay muted style={{ width: '40%' }} ref={localVideo} />
      <video autoPlay style={{ width: '40%' }} ref={remoteVideo} />
      <Button onClick={() => handleOnClick} size="large">Start Call</Button>
      <Countdown timeData={props}/>
    </>
  );
}

export default CallPaneCaller;
```

EDIT TO SHOW FURTHER METHODS AS REQUESTED:

Below I need to assign `remoteVideo` to a component JSX element in the same way as above, and as per the answer am showing the difficulty I'm having.

`remoteVideo` gets assigned in the `gotRemoteStreams` (second from the bottom) function which is called inside the function start, so there is a further scope issue:

```
var localStream;
var remoteVideo;
var peerConnection;
var uuid;
var serverConnection;

var peerConnectionConfig = {
  'iceServers': [
    { 'urls': 'stun:stun.stunprotocol.org:3478' },
    { 'urls': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
  ]
};

uuid = createUUID();

serverConnection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8444');
serverConnection.onmessage = gotMessageFromServer;

var constraints = {
  video: true,
  audio: true,
};

if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(getUserMediaSuccess).catch(errorHandler);
} else {
  alert('Your browser does not support getUserMedia API');
}

function getUserMediaSuccess(stream) {
  localStream = stream;
}

  export function setSrcObject(localVideo) {
  localVideo.srcObject = localStream;
  }

// ===================================================================

//  CALL ONCLICK
export function start(isCaller) {
  // CALL CONTACT VIA SOCKET IO
  peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(peerConnectionConfig);
  peerConnection.onicecandidate = gotIceCandidate;
  peerConnection.ontrack = gotRemoteStream;
  peerConnection.addStream(localStream);
  if (isCaller) {
    peerConnection.createOffer().then(createdDescription).catch(errorHandler);
  }
}

// ===================================================================

function gotMessageFromServer(message) {
  if (!peerConnection) start(false);

  var signal = JSON.parse(message.data);

  // Ignore messages from ourself
  if (signal.uuid === uuid) return;

  if (signal.sdp) {
    peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(signal.sdp)).then(function () {
      // Only create answers in response to offers
      if (signal.sdp.type === 'offer') {
        peerConnection.createAnswer().then(createdDescription).catch(errorHandler);
      }
    }).catch(errorHandler);
  } else if (signal.ice) {
    peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(signal.ice)).catch(errorHandler);
  }
}

function gotIceCandidate(event) {
  if (event.candidate != null) {
    console.log('sending')
    serverConnection.send(JSON.stringify({ 'ice': event.candidate, 'uuid': uuid }));
  }
}

function createdDescription(description) {
  console.log('got description');
  peerConnection.setLocalDescription(description).then(function () {
    serverConnection.send(JSON.stringify({ 'sdp': peerConnection.localDescription, 'uuid': uuid }));
  }).catch(errorHandler);
}


function gotRemoteStream(event) {
  console.log('got remote stream');
  remoteVideo.srcObject = event.streams[0];
}


function errorHandler(error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

And my component which I've started to set up in the same way but am not sure how to handle it on the service side:

```
import React from 'react';
import Countdown from './Countdown';
import { makeOutGoing } from '../services/WebSocketService'
import { Button } from 'antd';
import { start, setSrcObject, setSrcObjectRemote } from '../services/CallCallerService'

function CallPaneCaller(props) {

console.log("SENDER")

const handleOnClick = () => {
  start(true)
  makeOutGoing(props)
}

  return (
    <>
      <video autoPlay muted style={{ width: '40%' }} ref={localVideo => setSrcObject(localVideo)} />
      <video autoPlay style={{ width: '40%' }} ref={remoteVideo => setSrcObjectRemote(remoteVideo)} />
      <Button onClick={handleOnClick} size="large">Start Call</Button>
      <Countdown timeData={props}/>
    </>
  );
}

export default CallPaneCaller;
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the refs in the service?

Comment: @AvinKavish well I'm thinking that I no longer need to use `useRef` in the service as I was just using it before to pass `localVideo` to the `<video>` JSX element in the component. What I need to be able to do is pass `localVideo` from the service to the component so I can then use `useRef` to assign it to the video element.

Comment: hmm.. this is more of a design issue than a `useRef` issue. One option is to pass the ref as a function parameter when you want to start playback. the other option is to have a `setVideoRef()` function that sets the ref in the service.

Comment: Yes, thanks @AvinKavish - not sure how to pass it to the component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use the callback form of the `ref` attribute so that you can set the `srcObject` anytime the ref changes to the `localStream` variable that holds your stream. For that purpose, export a `setSrcObject` function from your service.

```
<video autoPlay muted style={{ width: '40%' }} ref={video => setSrcObject(video)} />


/* service */
export function setSrcObject(video) {
   video.srcObject = localStream;
}

function getUserMediaSuccess(stream) {
  localStream = stream;
  // localVideo.srcObject = stream; // <--- no longer needed as it is handled by the callback above.
}
```

The other options is to pass the ref created in `useRef` to the service

```
export function setLocalVideoRef(ref){
    localVideo = ref
    localVideo.current && localVideo.current.srcObject = localStream
}

function getUserMediaSuccess(stream) {
  localStream = stream;
  localVideo && localVideo.current && localVideo.current.srcObject = stream; // <--- Remains as is
}



...
localVideo = useRef();
setLocalVideoRef(localVideo)
```

To address the remote stream, you can create a `remoteStream` variable and hold the stream till the `setSrcObjectRemote()` is called.

```
let localStream;
let remoteSream;

function gotRemoteStream(event) {
  console.log('got remote stream');
  remoteStream = event.streams[0];
}

export function setSrcObjectRemote(video) {
  video.srcObject = remoteStream;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is working for the first option is working for the local video! I now have to do the same thing for remote video - I have tried using the same approach but the set up is a little bit different but is a similar scenario - You can see i the component that I also have this line `<video autoPlay style={{ width: '40%' }} ref={remoteVideo} />`. In the service `remoteVideo` is assigned in this function 
`function gotRemoteStream(event) {
  console.log('got remote stream');
  remoteVideo.srcObject = event.streams[0];
}`

It is called inside `start`. How can I approach?

Comment: Edit the question with the method please.